# Syntax to assign a method to a variable/property

Tags: php, functional-programming, anonymous-function, php-5.5

The following is very simplified example. I am wondering if it is possible in PHP and if so, what would be the right syntax.

```
class A{
   private $func = null;

   private default_func(){
       return $this;
   }

   public function __construct(callable $user_func=null){
      if($user_func){
          $this->func = $user_func;
      else{
          $this->func = $this->default_func; ********* NOT WORKING ******
      }

    }

    public function run(){
      $this->func();*************** NOT WORKING IF USER DOES NOT GIVE def func
  }
}

//NOT WORKING
$C = new A;
$C->run();

//WORKS
$D = new A(function(){echo 1;});
$D->run();
```

What I try here to give a developer the ability to send a function into a class to run-time override the default behavior.
**I am fully aware I could simply call the default function in the else, but as stated before, this is an over simplified example. In reality there are many "default" functions.**

Comment: Callables cant be member properties when you call them. Havent tried it but try assigning it to a local variable first then assign that to func

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include your default function as a closure, like so

```
class A{
   private $func = null;

   public function __construct(callable $user_func=null){
      if($user_func){
          $this->func = $user_func;
      else{
          $this->func = function(){
                    return $this;
          } 
      }

      $this->func();
  }
}
```

Comment: Although it would seems @Andrey solution should work, it does not on my php build. While yours does.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `call_user_func()` to call the function you need.  This should let you manage which one you want to call.

```
  public function __construct(callable $user_func=null){
      if($user_func){
          $this->func = $user_func;
      else{
          $this->func = [$this, 'default_func'];
      }

      call_user_func($this->func);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this:

```
   class A{
       private $func = null;

       private $default_func = function(){
           return $this;
       }

       public function __construct(callable $user_func=null){
          if($user_func){
              $this->func = $user_func;
          } else{
              $this->func = $this->default_func;
          }

          $this->func();
      }
    }
```

but better:

```
        class A{
           private $func = function(){
               return $this;
           };

           public function __construct(callable $user_func=null){
              if($user_func){
                  $this->func = $user_func;
              }

              $this->func();
          }
        }
```

Comment: I like this idea better than mine.  Your 2nd example is much cleaner :)

Comment: For what php version is this solution?

Comment: php 5.3+ of course. Using closure functions. http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php

Comment: Seems not to work on my php build, strange. I can't define a closure like that as a property, only assign it inside a method.